# What is a good way to think about the continuous random variable paradox?

Tags: probability-theory

While transitioning from discrete random variables to continuous random variables, I came across the argument that a continuous random variable can take possibly infinite values. Therefore, the probability that it takes **a particular value** is 0.

However, if all values are taken with 0 probability, then ultimately their sum will end up being 0 (which should really be 1).

Comment: This isn't a paradox because integration is not the same thing as summation.

Comment: Integration is basically the same thing as summation, the point is that summation can only be defined cogently if one is summing at most countably many nonzero terms.

Comment: @Did: Indeed, that's a better phrasing.

Comment: @someoneyouknow you know Sorry, I don't quite get your comment. I'm not even going to the PMFs and PDFs. My point is that even if it's a continuous RV and I go on adding the probabilities for each point, I'd end up with 0.

Comment: @martingale Did you read my comment? I am asking because your last comment simply restates the same (mistaken) position...

Answer (score 2):

Its a common misunderstanding to equate $P(Z)=0$ with the statement " Z *cannot* happen". If $|\Omega|<\infty$, then $P(Z)=0$ **does** mean that $Z$ cannot happen. However, if $|\Omega|=\infty$ then we need to use the *[transfinite numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_number)* to determine the "size" of $\Omega$. In these cases, all we know about events with $0$ probability is that $|\omega \in \Omega : \omega \in A|<|\Omega|=\aleph_i$.

In your case, any countably infinite set of real numbers will have probability zero if the underlying process is continuous (i.e, $|\Omega|=\aleph_1$with no "dirac deltas" or other such things to add in point probabilities), which implies that any such a set occurs only a countably infinite number of times. Going one level down: if you have a positive, unbounded, discrete RV, then $P(A)=0$ implies that the event $A$ will only occur a *finite* number of times over an *infinite* sequence of trials. Hence, it will occur but its probability will approach zero as you perform more trials...